# Need to create upper triangular matrix but the loops are not working properly

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi I am trying to make a matrix upper triangular by using elementary row operations

```
a = [1 1 0 1;2 1 -1 1;4 -1 -2 2;3 -1 -1 1]

function [c,d,e] = elim(a)
for i = 2:4
    a(i,:) = a(i,:) - a(1,:)*(a(i,1)/a(1,1))
end
c = a

for j=3:4
    c(j,:) = c(j,:) - c(1,:)*(c(j,1)/c(1,1))
end
d = c

for k=4:4
    d(k,:) = d(k,:) - d(1,:)*(d(k,1)/d(1,1))
end

e = d
```

and the output is

```
   1   1   0   1
   0  -1  -1  -1
   0  -5  -2  -2
   0  -4  -1  -2
```

so only the first column has been changed by the first 'for' loop in the code and the rest of the two 'for' loops seem to be not working. Any help?

Comment: Actually I am trying to do it manually without using any built-in function

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dmitri for the insight; I made a general program as follows

```
% this program takes input as a square matrix with arguments for 
% function as the matrix itself(a) and the order of the matrix(m)

function [c] = elim_ut_gen(a,m)
for j=1:(m-1)
    for i = (j+1):m
        a(i,:) = a(i,:) - a(j,:)*(a(i,j)/a(j,j))

    end
end

c=a

a =

 1     1     0     1
 2     1    -1     1
 4    -1    -2     2
 3    -1    -1     1


ans =

     1     1     0     1
     0    -1    -1    -1
     0     0     3     3
     0     0     0    -1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few minor mistakes in your function. Below they are fixed

```
function [c,d,e] = elim(a)
c = a;
for i = 2:4
    c(i,:) = c(i,:) - c(1,:)*(c(i,1)/c(1,1));
end

d = c;
for j=3:4
    d(j,:) = d(j,:) - d(2,:)*(d(j,2)/d(2,2));
end

e = d;
for k=4:4
    e(k,:) = e(k,:) - e(3,:)*(e(k,3)/e(3,3));
end
end
```

On subsequent steps of elimination you should use the elements of the corresponding row. That is on step two you should use the second row to eliminate elements of the second column, and so on.

The result:

```
>> [c,d,e] = elim(a)
c =

   1   1   0   1
   0  -1  -1  -1
   0  -5  -2  -2
   0  -4  -1  -2

d =

   1   1   0   1
   0  -1  -1  -1
   0   0   3   3
   0   0   3   2

e =

   1   1   0   1
   0  -1  -1  -1
   0   0   3   3
   0   0   0  -1
```

There are a few problems remaining:

1. The function should check if the diagonal element used for elimination is not zero and report an error
2. The function can easily be generalized to handle matrices of arbitrary shape.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I have made correction and generalized and added it as an answer here

Answer (score 0):

What I love about Matlab is that, for a majority of situations, there is no need to reinvent the wheel:

```
a = [1 1 0 1;2 1 -1 1;4 -1 -2 2;3 -1 -1 1];
e = tril(a,-1) + triu(a);
```

Comment: I guess you missed this comment above: "Actually I am trying to do it manually without using any built-in function."

Comment: Ah damn, I literally skipped it :O